# Push notification can't be activated in certain phone models and OS

Tags: ios, push-notification

I'm experiencing a bug that only occurs in iPhone X/XS running iOS 16.2. I cannot tap the push notification when the app is already active. I would like to trigger a function when the push notification is tapped.

When the app is on the background, it worked. But when the app is already active / on the foreground, it didn't. I tried this on an iPhone 8 Plus running iOS 16.2.1 and iPhone 14 and iPhone XR running iOS 17.1.2, but this bug didn't occur (ie. the tap was working and I can trigger the `didReceiveResponse` and `willPresentNotification` callbacks).

Can anyone please explain this behavior?

Comment: Usually you implement `UNNotificationCenterDelegate` method [`userNotificationCenter(_:willPresent:withCompletionHandler:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenterdelegate/usernotificationcenter(_:willpresent:withcompletionhandler:))  to indicate how you want to handle notifications when the app is running. Have you done that? If so, we probably need to see a MRE of your implementation. If not, have your notification center’s delegate implement that.

Comment: Like I said above. Everything works fine except in some devices with iOS 16.2. The `userNotificationCenter(_:willPresent:withCompletionHandler:)`. The callback is triggered in iPhone 8 running iOS 16.2.1 and iPhone XR / iPhone 14 running iOS 17.1.2

Comment: I hear you, but I just tested in iOS 17.4.1 and with the `willPresent` rendition, it works fine. I get my alerts while the app is running. I haven’t tested on iOS 17.1.2, specifically, but it is more likely that the problem rests elsewhere, likely something on the device settings or the like. Or maybe something in your `willPresent` implementation (which we cannot comment on without seeing it). I’d try using `Logger` to record calls to `willPresent` and watching from macOS console and make sure it’s getting called, like you think. But some OS version related problem is exceedingly unlikely.

Comment: In short, we need to be able to [reproduce it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to comment further.

Comment: @Rob that's the problem. I know that we need to reproduce it but I can't even reproduce it except in two of our many test devices. And both are using iOS 16.2. While some newer ones which use iOS 17, it worked fine. Heck, my own device which use 16.2.1 worked fine. 

Also I've added an `oslog` at the start of `willPresent` but it doesn't log anything at all on the faulty devices. While on the ones which are working fine, it did. So I don't think the implementation is the issue. I'm at my wits' end and just need someone to give any idea about what made the push notif seemed to be untappable.

Comment: Sorry, I can't really give any other information because I don't even know what information to give here. It was tested on some of our client's test devices. This holds the UAT up and the client won't sign anything before it got fixed. Although on their own newer test devices, it is working as it should. Heck, it was even working on devices running iOS 14. Only on those two damned devices that this bug appeared.